# Pandas, Handling "Out of bounds timestamp..."

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I have a df with certain features as object types which I want to convert to datetypes.   When I attempt to convert using pd.to_datetime, some of these features return an "Out of bounds timestamp"  error message.   To address this, I add "errors= coerce" argument, then seek to drop all NAs which result.  For example:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[date_features], infer_datetime_format = True, errors = 'coerce')
df[date_features].dropna(inplace= True)
```

Yet, this doesn't seem to convert the features to 'datetime:' ("maturity_date" is one of the date_features I am trying to convert to datetime).

```
df.[maturity_date].describe()

count        3355323
unique         11954
top       2015-12-01
freq           29607
Name: maturity_date, dtype: object
```

Furthermore, if I again try to convert maturity_date using pd.to_datetime without "coerce" I get the "Out of bounds" timestamp.

I hope I have described this problem thoroughly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` is not an in place operation. Assign the result back.

Comment: `df['date_features'] = pd.to_datetime(...)`

Comment: Also, calling `dropna` on a column does nothing. If you want to drop Null rows, use `df = df.dropna(subset=['date_features'])`

Comment: Try implementing these changes in your code, and let me know if they work.

Comment: Still labels features as dtype "object."

Comment: @COLDSPEED - See modification of question above...

Comment: Huh... it's been solved perfectly. `describe` returns a new Series, and the `dtype` describes _that series_, and not `maturity_date` in any way.

Comment: I rolled back your edit and converted my comments into an answer, since they evidently worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` is not an inplace operation. Your code performs a conversion, and proceeds to discard the result. The right thing to do would be to assign the result back, like so -

```
df['date_features'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_features, errors='coerce')
```

Furthermore, don't call `dropna` on a column that belongs to a dataframe, as this will not modify the dataframe (even with `inplace=True`). Instead, call `dropna` on the *dataframe* with a `subset` attribute -

```
df.dropna(subset='date_features', inplace=True)
```

Now, as observed, `maturity_date` will look like this -

```
results["maturity_date"].head()

0   2017-04-01
1   2017-04-01
2   2017-04-01
3   2016-01-15
4   2016-01-15
Name: maturity_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

As you can see, the `dtype` is `datetime64`, meaning this operation worked. If you call `describe()`, it performs a few standard aggregations and returns the results as a *new series*. This series is displayed in the same way as any other, including a `dtype` description that applies to *it*, not the column it is describing.

Comment: @COLDSPEED - wow, I learned alot from your reply - I never realized describe worked the way you said.    Thank you very much.